# Problem keeping a 3D cube correctly roll on its edges using rotate and translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

Please see my js Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/5ozqg9uL/3/

```js
var xAngle = 0;
var yAngle = 0;
var xPos  = 0;
var yPos  = 0;

$('body').keydown(function(evt) {
    if(evt.keyCode == 37) 
    {
        //left
        yAngle -= 90;
        xPos -= 100;
        //rotate and translate the position of the cube
        $('#cube')[0].style["WebkitTransform"] = "translateX("+xPos+"px) translateY("+yPos+"px) rotateX(" + xAngle + "deg) rotateY(" + yAngle + "deg)";
    }
    if(evt.keyCode == 39) 
    {
        //right
        yAngle -= -90;
        xPos -= -100;
        //rotate and translate the position of the cube
        $('#cube')[0].style["WebkitTransform"] = "translateX("+xPos+"px) translateY("+yPos+"px) rotateX(" + xAngle + "deg) rotateY(" + yAngle + "deg)";
    }
    if(evt.keyCode == 38) 
    {
        //up
        xAngle -= -90;
        yPos -= 100;
        //rotate and translate the position of the cube
        $('#cube')[0].style["WebkitTransform"] = "translateX("+xPos+"px) translateY("+yPos+"px) rotateX(" + xAngle + "deg) rotateY(" + yAngle + "deg)";
    }
    if(evt.keyCode == 40) 
    {
        //down
        xAngle -= 90;
        yPos -= -100;
        //rotate and translate the position of the cube
        $('#cube')[0].style["WebkitTransform"] = "translateX("+xPos+"px) translateY("+yPos+"px) rotateX(" + xAngle + "deg) rotateY(" + yAngle + "deg)";
    }
});
```

```css
#scene {
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
}

#cube {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

   
}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    height: 85px;
    width: 85px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: grey;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.7);
}

#cube .one  {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

#cube .two {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);
}

#cube .three {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

#cube .four {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(50px);
}

#cube .five {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

#cube .six {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="scene">
    Press the arrow keys...
    <div id="cube">
        <div class="face one">
            Face 1
        </div>
        <div class="face two">
            Face 2
        </div>
        <div class="face three">
            Face 3
        </div>
        <div class="face four">
            Face 4
        </div>
        <div class="face five">
            Face 5
        </div>
        <div class="face six">
            Face 6
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have a css3 3d cube which you can move by using your arrow keys. You can move it to the left, to the right, up and down. To achieve this I store the position and angle in various vars:

```
var xAngle = 0;
var yAngle = 0;
var xPos  = 0;
var yPos  = 0;
```

The cube always "rolls" correctly on its edges going up or down, but for left and right this is not always the case.

**Example:**

1. At start press the left arrow key and the right as many times as you like. The cube behaves correctly
2. Now press down once and then left twice (or right) again. The cube now rolls incorrectly
3. BUT, if you press up or down again, it rolls correctly again going up or down

So the issue only seems to be with going left or right. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you look closely when you trigger the left/right keys they are pivoting on the same pivot point regardless of what face is showing. For example... the cube starts at face 2 and when you turn right it pivots on face 6. Now go down and then left, again, it pivots on face 6. Donw once more to face 4 (upside down) and it pivots on face 6... I would argue that this is likely default behavior of the code as is...

Comment: if you rotate the `y` before the `x` when moving left or right it gets a wee bit closer.  It only then misbehaves when you change axis

Comment: If you want the cube always have the same ***roll*** - *pivot* behavior of when you press the left key the bottom face rotates on the horizontal axis, then you likely have to code so you can find what face is actually adhered to the pivot at the time the event fires...

Comment: I see what you guys are saying about the pivot, but I have no idea how to address this. Searched google but didn't find anything useful. Also I don't understand why it doesn't affect the up and down roll? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider 3 kind of rotations which mean 3 different axis and not 2 like you are doing.

Here is an updated version of your code. Notice how I am updating the angles of an axis based on others axis.

Still not a perfect solution since I found some strange movements (probably some edge cases I missed) but a good starting point.

```js
var xAngle = 0;
var yAngle = 0;
var zAngle = 0;
var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;

$('body').keydown(function(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 37) {
    //left
    if (xAngle % 180 == 0)
      yAngle -= 90;
    else
      zAngle -= 90;
    xPos -= 100;
  }
  if (evt.keyCode == 39) {
    //right
    if (xAngle % 180 == 0)
      yAngle -= -90;
    else
      zAngle -= -90;

    xPos -= -100;
  }
  if (evt.keyCode == 38) {
    //up
    if (yAngle % 180 == 0)
      xAngle -= -90;
    else
      zAngle -= -90;
    yPos -= 100;
  }
  if (evt.keyCode == 40) {
    //down
    if (yAngle % 180 == 0)
      xAngle -= 90;
    else
      zAngle -= 90;
    yPos -= -100;
  }
  $('#cube').css('transform', "translateX(" + xPos + "px) translateY(" + yPos + "px) rotateX(" + xAngle + "deg) rotateY(" + yAngle + "deg) rotateZ(" + zAngle + "deg)");
});
```

```css
#scene {
  padding: 10px;
  perspective: 800;
}

#cube {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: transform 0.4s linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: grey;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.7);
}

#cube .one {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

#cube .two {
  transform: translateZ(50px);
}

#cube .three {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

#cube .four {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(50px);
}

#cube .five {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

#cube .six {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scene">
  Press the arrow keys...
  <div id="cube">
    <div class="face one">
      Face 1
    </div>
    <div class="face two">
      Face 2
    </div>
    <div class="face three">
      Face 3
    </div>
    <div class="face four">
      Face 4
    </div>
    <div class="face five">
      Face 5
    </div>
    <div class="face six">
      Face 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah the z-axis! Thanks for this example, will play around with it and see if I can get the kinks out of it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your issue is the translations are happening all relative to the original orientation, and you're not accounting for the fact that your positive x,y are different on each rotation.